# How to count sum of two columns in the results record of the table in AggreGate IoT platform

Tags: iot

I’m a newbie in AggreGate IoT platform and I’m searched information in the documentation, but did not find the answer. I have table with many columns and I need to sum numbers in each column and add result in the last row. Please help me, I have no idea haw I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, you have to use an expression:

```
   addRecords(st("table",table("<<value1><I>><<value2> 
   <I>>",1,1,2,2)),evaluate(print({env/table}," 
   {value1}","+")),evaluate(print({env/table},"{value2}","+")))
```